# I want to convert radio buttons into star for star rating . i followed various tutorials but none works for me

Tags: javascript, php, css

```js
$(".rating input:radio").attr("checked", false);

$('.rating input').click(function() {
  $(".rating span").removeClass('checked');
  $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
});

$('input:radio').change(function() {
  var userRating = this.value;
  alert(userRating);
});
```

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.rating span {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.rating span input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rating span label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

.rating span:hover~span label,
.rating span:hover label,
.rating span.checked label,
.rating span.checked~span label {
  background: #F90;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="star.php">
    <div class="rating">
      <span><input type="radio" name="ratingg" id="str5" value="5"><label for="str5"></label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="ratingg" id="str4" value="4"><label for="str4"></label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="ratingg" id="str3" value="3"><label for="str3"></label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="ratingg" id="str2" value="2"><label for="str2"></label></span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="ratingg" id="str1" value="1"><label for="str1"></label></span>
    </div>
    <label for="review">Your review about the place.</label>
    <textarea name="review" id="review" col="5" row="30"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

everything is working fine.i Just need these radio buttons to be displayed as star .help me with css Please.

Comment: http://antennaio.github.io/jquery-bar-rating/  use jquery plugin

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/build-php-mysql-5-star-rating-system-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: `.checked label::after { content: "⭐" }`

Comment: @mplungjan great solution but bad for devices that don't support unicode [square only](https://imgur.com/inB5Zre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use font awesome icon here is the link

https://fontawesome.com/icons

search for the star icon you get the suitable icon as you want and put it into the label tag you have put in your code.

```
<label><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
```

this is the JS file link please download the file from here which is used to show the icons.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eLhUjVd4ldCFmIgJLkUtFVfLUjEYZdW5/view?usp=sharing

and then make replace the following css code which you have done.

```
.rating span label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

.rating span:hover~span label,
.rating span:hover label,
.rating span.checked label,
.rating span.checked~span label {
  color: #F90;
}
```